# how to make the menu appear in the page using only javascript and how to fix it

Tags: javascript

so i am quite new to the programming, can some tell me how to fix this code so it shows a menu in the page this is the udacity nano degree project landing page.
here is my code:

```
 function fun (){
     // this code to loop our code 
  for (let i=0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
     const sectionID = section.id;
     const datanav = document.getElementById('data-nav');
     // we created new element li
        const linkfirst = document.createElement('li');
        // we created new element a
        const Alink = document.createElement('a');
         
          let textContent = document.createTextNode('datanav');
          Alink.textContent= datanav;
          linkfirst.appendChild(Alink);
          }
          // this code will make an event when we press on it it will take us to the right section through the page 
          
          fun.preventDefault();
          //this code wii make us able to scroll in a smoth way through the page
          element.scroll({
           top: 100,
           left: 100,
           behavior: 'smooth'
         });
         fun.addEventListener("click", fun );
         const clicked = document.querySelector('#' + datanav)
          clicked.scrollIntoView(behavior,smooth);
         document.getElementById('navbar__list').innerHTML= fun();
           fun('click');
```

Comment: Can you please add the html as well and put it in a runnable code snippet? Please also define what "making it work" means and what your actual problem is.

Comment: Please, create a [mcve] for us, it will help a lot to help you

Comment: You may have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674396/how-to-create-a-menu-using-only-javascript-code).

Comment: thank you so much andria and everyone how answered your answer is what i need